# Why does cut not work here as expected with the delimiter?

Tags: text-processing, cut

I have this file as input:

```
root      1243  0.0  0.0  65508  6036 ?        Ss   Apr30   0:05 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      7385  0.0  0.1 152932 10644 ?        Ss   16:22   0:00 sshd: per1 [priv]
per2  7425  0.0  0.0 152932  6216 ?        S    16:22   0:00 sshd: per2@pts/7
root      8256  0.0  0.1 152876 10240 ?        Ss   16:32   0:00 sshd: per3 [priv]
per3  8298  0.0  0.0 152876  5308 ?        S    16:32   0:00 sshd: per3@pts/9
```

I want to be able to select the first column of unique names:

`cut -f 1 file.txt | sort | uniq` but this will not work. I have to do `cut -f 1 -d " " file.txt ...`

Why do I add in this `-d 1`? It is my understanding that when the spaces between the columns are **not** tabs, we must write what it is. In this case it is `" "`, so thats why we write it. Is this correct?

**Then how do I select the 2nd column here?** I simply changed the `cut -f 1` to `cut -f 2` but this did not do it. My output for that was a bunch of empty lines? Why? Why did it work for `cut -f 1` but not 2?

Comment: So are you saying that if the distance between the first and second column was only one space, then it would work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first *space*-separated field with `cut`, then you have to tell it to use spaces instead of the default of TABs:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut

> -d, --delimiter=DELIM
>
> use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

As soon as you tell `cut` to use spaces as the delimiter, that's what it uses, and so "field 2" becomes the first byte(s) following the first space (until it sees another delimiter); in your case, that's a space.

Use this data as an illustrative example:

`root 1space  2space   3space`

... where there's one space before `1space`, two before `2space` and three before `3space`.

```
$ seq 1 7 | while read index; do echo "$index" - "$(cut -d' ' -f $index < input)"; done
1 - root
2 - 1space
3 -
4 - 2space
5 -
6 -
7 - 3space
```

Since you have a variable number of spaces separating the fields in the input, I'd suggest:

- If you're OK "changing" the data, use `sed` to reduce multiple spaces to one, as steeldriver showed: `sed 's/  */ /g' < input | cut -d' ' -f2`.
- Otherwise, consider a tool like `awk` that splits fields on multiple subsequent field separators: `awk '{print $2}' < input`

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, I don't see how the `first` field is separated by spaces? It is the first field. The second field I can surely say is separated by spaces on both sides.

Comment: The first field ends at the first space (delimiter).